# How to edit the applications listed in the Windows 10 Start menu

Tags: start-menu, windows-10-preview

I'm using the Windows 10 Technical Preview with the Start menu. When you access the All Apps section of the menu, some of my programs are listed and some aren't, some programs remain there after I uninstall them, etc. The right-click options to manually delete things from the menu are gone, and `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` no longer seems to have any effect on that list. How can the All Apps list be manually edited?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.  Basically, you use Explorer to browse to the folder (as you indicated), with the following paths:

- `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
- `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows Ease of Access`

There's a way to do it with environment variables, but I only figured it out for the individual user.

`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6463/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-open-the-start-menu-folder-in-windows-7/

Comment: Note that after making changes, allow a few seconds for Windows to perform some behind-the-scenes caching (or reboot) to see the effect.